# Browsers stick with old html and JS cache

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, browser-cache

I am working on a very simple demo on .net MVC4, very simple, html page code less than 100 lines, with about 30 lines of JavaScript code in a separate JS file, no server side call. Also use jQuery 1.12 and bootstrap libs.

However I had trouble since last night, I added onclick() trigger to a button, but it never work. From developer tool I can see all the changes were gone even I had saved changes in HTML and JS file, and rebuild everything, elements from developer tool window shows old html and js file, without my change.

So below are what I did: (Note I did these in both IE 11 and Chrome)

1) "F5", not work

2) Ctrl + R, not work

3) Went to setting, cleared everything(history, cache, etc..), not work

4) Disabled JS cache in developer tool, not work

5) Add version number as other person mentioned in Stack Overflow

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myfile.js?1500"></script>
```

not work

6)Then I created another js file with different name, copied all the js code to new file, **deleted old one**, re-add new one's reference to HTML.

let's say the old JS file is named "**renderControl.js**", then the new one I called it "**fkTest.js**"

Then I cleared everything I could. Then guess what? From developer tool, the html code remained in old one, I clicked tab "Sources", then I found old "**renderControl.js**" still under "Scripts" folder, which I had physically deleted.

Comment: The code is in your computer or in a server? Try to check cache settings on your HTTP server.

Comment: Sounds like you cached it server side, have you turned on output caching?

Comment: If you want that the solution of your 5th point works, that number have to change in each request.

Comment: @Pete I debug via VS, just now I went IIS, unchecked "Enable cache" and "Enable kernel cache", but still not work

Comment: @dlopez I did that..not work...

Comment: @MikeVelazco I run the web via VS2012, how I clear the VS cache?

Comment: if you delete the web.config does it break your site? if not then your site must be looking at a different directory (maybe you published it somewhere)

Comment: @Pete I excluded my web.config, then vs could rebuild, but if I run site, a popup says "Debugging Not Enabled" "coz debugging is not enabled in the web.config file"

Comment: @Pete Then I have two choices, one is add new web.config, or run without debugging. I tried the second one, page show up with old html and js code. Does this mean it is working at a different directory?

Comment: Is this happening while you are debugging in VS?

Comment: @whipdancer Yes. I resolved this by search the js file name through my drive, deleted all the found

Comment: You should add your solution as the answer and then accept it.  It may help someone else who runs into a similar problem.

Comment: @whipdancer Thanks, I added it to my post.

Comment: @Windtalker The proper way to do it is not to add [solved] to your title but to post your answer as an answer (not in the question itself). Then you can also accept your added answer as an actual solution.

Comment: @scrappedcola Sorry for late response. halfer has posted my answer, but I'll follow the rule next time. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP.)*

I resolved this by search the JS file name through my drive, deleted all the found.

Comment: @Windtalker: no worries. You can either accept this one (by clicking the tick mark to the left of it) or post your own answer if you want to keep the authorship (let me know and I can delete this one).